# Javascript procedure to decompress a string of decimal digits

Tags: javascript

I just started learning JavaScript and I'm extremely annoyed by it.

I want a procedure that decompresses a string of decimal digits like so:

"301051" means "3 zeros, a one, a zero, then 5 ones"

i.e.
"301051"---> "0001011111"

A string of digits of ones and zeros won't be changed at all (and also won't have any more than two consecutive 0's or 1's)

"01001100" ---> "01001100"

I started to work on it, but I'm churning out spaghetti code.

```
for (i = 0; i < thisString.length;)
{
  thisNum = thisString.charCodeAt(i);
  if (thisNum > 1)
  {
     substr = ""; 
     for (j = 0; j < thisNum; j++)
        subtr += thisString.charAt(i);
     if (i == 0)
    thisString = substr + thisString.substring(2
   }
}
```

I don't feel like finishing that because I'm sick of using the limited number of JavaScript string functions. I'm sure the geniuses at Stack Overflow have a 1-line solution for me. Right, guys????

Comment: Those one-line solutions are called Regular Expressions.

Comment: Your algorithm is broken, not JavaScript. It's a poor programmer that blames the language for their own shortcomings.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. If you had '32051' would this translate to 32 zeros and 5 ones?

Comment: @Fizz No, that would not be a valid string in the first place. A valid string cannot have two numbers from the  {2, 3, ..., 9} next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple algorithmic solution:

```
function decompress(str) {
    var result = "", char = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        char = str.charAt(i);
        console.log(char - '0');
        if (char > 1) {
            result += new Array(+char + 1).join(str.charAt(++i));
        } else {
            result += char;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And an even simpler regex solution:

```
function decompress(str) {
    return str.replace(/([2-9])(.)/g, function(m, a, b) { 
        return new Array(+a + 1).join(b);
    });
}
```

The only magic here is the `new Array(+a + 1).join(b)` (which is also used by both solutions). The first `+` turns `a` (or `char`) into a number. Then I create an array of a + 1 elements, and join them together with following character as 'glue'. The result is a string of `a` repetitions of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like:

```
function decompress(thisString) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < thisString.length; i += 2) {
    var thisNum = parseInt(thisString[i], 10);
    if (thisNum > 1) {
       for (var j = 0; j < thisNum; j++)
          result += thisString[i + 1];
    } else {
       result += (thisString[i] + thisString[i + 1]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You have a lot of variables, which are leaking as globals. Make sure you declare each of them using `var`.

Comment: Should the check also be for thisNum === 0, not just thisNum === 1? I'm thinking of the case where it starts with '0', it wouldn't hit any of the if-statement cases.